# I found a JSON file I want to use in PHP

Tags: php, json

I found a JSON file and I would like to use it for my PHP website, but I have never seen the JSON filetypes before, so i need help on how to implement it. The JSON file is (http://halocharts.com/2012/json_challenges.php).

Comment: RTFM: http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php

Comment: `json_decode(file_get_contents("http://halocharts.com/2012/json_challenges.php"));`

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - JSON Data Parsing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067544/php-json-data-parsing)

Comment: Hi there. Just so you know, if you ask too many questions that are downvoted and closed, your account may be restricted from asking new questions. Please refer to the FAQ to see what makes a good question here, and do _always_ search and research before you ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php

$raw=file_get_contents("http://halocharts.com/2012/json_challenges.php");
$raw=json_decode($raw,true);
```

Now you can access `$raw` at `DailyChallenges` with `$raw['DailyChallenges']`.