# How to parse a large javascript array of objects variable in php view preg_match?

Tags: php, preg-match

```
var skuProducts=[{"skuAttr":"200000828:200003982#C93A","skuPropIds":"200003982","skuVal":{"inventory":1,"isActivity":false,"skuCalPrice":"130.00","skuMultiCurrencyCalPrice":"130.0","skuMultiCurrencyDisplayPrice":"130.00","skuMultiCurrencyPrice":"US $130.00","skuPrice":"130.00"}},{"skuAttr":"200000828:200003983#C93A HDMI Cable","skuPropIds":"200003983","skuVal":{"inventory":1,"isActivity":false,"skuCalPrice":"135.00","skuMultiCurrencyCalPrice":"135.0","skuMultiCurrencyDisplayPrice":"135.00","skuMultiCurrencyPrice":"US $135.00","skuPrice":"135.00"}},{"skuAttr":"200000828:200003984#C93A Car Holder","skuPropIds":"200003984","skuVal":{"inventory":1,"isActivity":false,"skuCalPrice":"138.00","skuMultiCurrencyCalPrice":"138.0","skuMultiCurrencyDisplayPrice":"138.00","skuMultiCurrencyPrice":"US $138.00","skuPrice":"138.00"}},{"skuAttr":"200000828:200003985#C93A Stand Holder","skuPropIds":"200003985","skuVal":{"inventory":1,"isActivity":false,"skuCalPrice":"139.00","skuMultiCurrencyCalPrice":"139.0","skuMultiCurrencyDisplayPrice":"139.00","skuMultiCurrencyPrice":"US $139.00","skuPrice":"139.00"}},{"skuAttr":"200000828:200003986#C93S selected","skuPropIds":"200003986","skuVal":{"inventory":1,"isActivity":false,"skuCalPrice":"124.00","skuMultiCurrencyCalPrice":"124.0","skuMultiCurrencyDisplayPrice":"124.00","skuMultiCurrencyPrice":"US $124.00","skuPrice":"124.00"}}];

$subject = "abcdef";
$pattern = '/^def/';
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, 3);
print_r($matches);
```

how to parse a large javascript array of objects in php? like the above var

Comment: The 1st line is incomplete. Quite certain it can't be parsed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - JSON Data Parsing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067544/php-json-data-parsing)

Comment: there are a lot of "How to parse JSON with PHP" in Stack Overflow...

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$abc=json_decode( your javascript object);
```

Try sending the json object to php script using ajax

```
$.ajax({
url: "url of the php script",
type: "POST",
data: json object,
dataType: "json"
});
```

learn about [ajax](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp)

Comment: but how can I get it if its in the page, I need to parse it, also it is an array of objects, will it be decoded by json_decode?

Comment: do you want to convert the javascript object in the php format or what??? be clear

Comment: yes, but how to get it from the html page and only then convert

Comment: You can send it through **ajax** if you are familiar with it

Comment: the html page its no mine, but I need to get that var, if I get the content of the page, how can I parse that var skuProducts value view preg_match?, I just need a regexp

Answer (score 0):

I know what you are doing %username% ;)

it's just as simple as:

```
preg_match('/skuProducts=(.*);/', $message->body /*html you parse */ , $m);

$skuProducts = json_decode($m[1]);
```

But are you sure it is the safe method to get that data?